# Connect thermal printer through USB to my android tab

Tags: android, printing

I need to connect my android tab to a thermal printer does anyone have a solution for it I know as it can be done through IOIO Controller but apart from that is there a way to connect my tab to my android tab.

Note I need to connect only through usb not through bluetooth or wifi whcih I know can be done and I have did it.

Comment: What benefits You got if You connect printer via USB cable ? And what type of connector have Your android tab ? Is that the same printer witch You connected via wifi ? And check if that printer have driver for linux.

Comment: You need USB OTG cable. And driver for linux! http://www.printershare.com/help-android-usb.sdf

Comment: Guntis thanks for your answer  am in India so in many shops for billing they use the old  thermal printer (retail billing machine) which doesnt have bluetooth or wifi in it so do you have any idea on how to connect it to a android tab.

Comment: Guntis one more thing sorry I forgot to mention do you have any idea on how to connect a printer to android device through RS232 port .

Comment: You can try to use rs232 to usb converter (I do not know if it works). and again - it must have driver for linux (android).